# Is it bad practice to give Components attributes it won't use? React

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have a wrapper component that needs information about each child, is it a bad idea to use props to transport that information?
For example:

```
<MakeColorful>
 <div color="green">green</div>
 <div color="red">red</div>
</MakeColorful>
```

MakeColorful could access this via `child.props.color`.
Is this a bad pattern? Are there good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your hunch that this is a bad pattern is a good one.  There is no contract between the wrapper and it's children that you are honoring.  Say another developer comes in and wants to use `<MakeColorful>`, there isn't anything requiring them to ensure that the child elements contain that prop.

If you need to share props between the parent and the child then I would provide the props to the parent and then have them add those props to the child if necessary.

Without more context or a description of the use case you are trying to solve, it is hard to provide an alternative.

Comment: I find both solution quite hack-y, and there probably is no definite answer here, but with OP's solution, he can still have something like `children: PropTypes.shape({ props: PropTypes.shape({ color: PropTypes.string.isRequired }) })` for props validation of `<MakeColorful>` to cover the concern you've specified.